# Установка ALT Linux 6.0 Centaurus

Tags: linux

Скачал с местного торрент трекера записал образ на диск, но после перезагрузки компьютер принимает диск как пустой, т.е установка не начинается, то же самое и с флешкой. Что нужно сделать, чтобы программа установки запускалась?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала проверьте, что образ не битый (с помощью MD5 хэш-сумм) (и до записи, и после записи на диск). Либо скачайте образ с официального зеркала, например, [mirror.yandex.ru](http://mirror.yandex.ru/).

Answer (score 1):

Флэшку-то чем делали? Если сторонними инструментами не самого дистрибутива, то это ничего не значит. А вот CD - правильно сказали проверить целостность образа и потом записывать строго на самой медленной скорости. 90% проблем с загрузкой инсталляционного диска связаны с этим.

Comment: Для архива: точнее, http://altlinux.org/write

Answer (score 0):

Для архива: как правило, это непомерно "умная" софтина записи, которая испортила загрузочный образ, пытаясь сделать его... загрузочным.  Вот официальные [рекомендации](http://altlinux.org/write) (с тех пор мы постарались обвешать все места, где можно об это предупреждение споткнуться, как минимум на вики).